# Targeting table cells with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a javascript function that inserts `tr` and `td` dynamically based on how many rows and columns a user specifies. I'm trying to write another function that will allow me do certain things when a particular cell of the table is clicked on.

This is the function that generates the table

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {

        numOfRow = $('#height').val();
        numOfCol = $('#width').val();
        const body = $('.grid-canvas');

        for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRow; i++) {
            let row = $('<tr id=\'' + i + '\'></tr>');

            for (col = 1; col <= numOfCol; col++) {
                row.append('<td id=\'' + col + '\'></td>');
            }

            body.append(row);
        }
    });
```

This is what my dynamically generated table looks like

```
<table class="table-bordered">
<tbody class="grid-canvas">
    <tr id="1">
        <td id="1"></td>
        <td id="2"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Tried severally to use the index but its obvious to me that it's not working. However this is what my function to do something when a cell is clicked on is

```
let boxToFill = $('td').index();
    $(boxToFill).click(function() {
        console.log(boxToFill);
    });
```

Please what is the right way to target specific table cell? This is a learning process for me in working with javascript.

Comment: You can't have the same id multiple times. (example, your id "1")

Comment: @TakitIsy not even when the `tr` have different ids too? What will be the best way to do it then?

Comment: @Mena yes, id should unique on the entire DOM, unless some CSS code and dom selectors might not work as you expect them

Comment: @Mena, I added a suggestion of ids in the HTML code of my answer. Feel free to comment it if anything! Anyway, What do you want to do `onclick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put everything in a small example

```js
function fillBox(element) {
    // do something with element
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#submit').on('click', function () {

        numOfRow = 3;
        numOfCol = 5;
        const body = $('.grid-canvas');

        for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRow; i++) {
            let row = $('<tr id=\'' + i + '\'></tr>');

            for (col = 1; col <= numOfCol; col++) {
                row.append('<td onclick="fillBox(this)" id=\'r' + i + 'c' + + col + '\'>test</td>');
            }
            body.append(row);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
tr{
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">create</button>
<table class="table-bordered">
    <tbody class="grid-canvas">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried adapting my build function, so I put the fillBox function above the build function but I get the error `fillBox(this)` is not defined. Same thing when i did this `fillBox($(this))`

Comment: Yes fillBox($(this)) shouldn work ;), I'll check it out

Comment: Why is the fillBox function outside document.ready? I kept all my code inside document.ready and it didn't work then. Doing it the way you did works now. Please explain

Comment: As `fillBox` does not need to wait for the dom to be loaded it can be outside. Only functionality that works with the dom needs to be inside `document.ready`. If your question is answered, please mark the answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.index()` was a really good idea.
You don't even need to add `id`s to your `td`s if you use that.

Here is it, with my corrections, it's an easy way to save which `td` you clicked,
and then use it in another function:
(See comments in my code for more details)

```js
// I tried to use the same way of doing that you did, 'index()' was a good idea…
// … but with my corrections and some more functionnalities. :)
var td_picked; // Using this external variable to show how you can use it in another function
$('td').click(function() {
  // You could use anything from the td here, using $(this) selector
  td_picked = $(this); // Save the td you clicked in the variable
});

// Added button to display the td you last clicked
$('#button1').click(function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(
    "Last clicked:\n",
    "tr index", $(td_picked).parent().index(), ",",
    "td index", $(td_picked).index(), ",",
    "content:", $(td_picked).html()
  );
});
```

```css
/* Some CSS, to make it nicer */

.table-bordered {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-bordered td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- See my suggestions of id if you need to continue using it -->
<table class="table-bordered">
  <tbody class="grid-canvas">
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td id="td1-1">Content 1-1</td>
      <td id="td1-2">Content 1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
      <td id="td2-1">Content 2-1</td>
      <td id="td2-2">Content 2-2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button id="button1">Show my picked</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ran your code snippet and it works well but I tried something similar and nothing is logged in the console. No error as well, this is my code
`let selectedCell;
    $('td').click(function() {
        selectedCell = $(this);
        console.log($(selectedCell).index());
    })` Am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

I'd bind the `.on('click')` over at the table itself and just use a specific selector, in your case `td` will probably suffice, for the click event; see the example below:

```js
$("#clickable_table").on('click', "td" ,function() {
    console.log($(this).html()); // Just print the content for demo purposes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered" id="clickable_table"> <!-- Added an ID -->
    <tbody class="grid-canvas">
        <tr id="1">
            <td id="1">TD 1</td>
            <td id="2">TD 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// I tried to use the same way of doing that you did, 'index()' was a good idea…
// … but with my corrections. :)
let tds = $('td');
$(tds).click(function() {
  console.log($(this).index()+' '+$(this).parent().index());
});
```

```css
/* Some CSS, to make it nicer */

.table-bordered{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-bordered td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-bordered">
  <tbody class="grid-canvas">
    <tr id="1">
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This if you want keep the row number too.

Comment: You copied my answer without even removing the comments. Really?!

Comment: And please don't use `+' '+` in the console, but only a `,`. If you want to copy, do it right.

Comment: Excuse me I only had changed your response adding row number.